# pyinstaller is not going well can I know some other ways to convert .py file to .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2exe

when I created .py to .exe with pyinstaller my .exe file is not working can anyone one suggest some other ways to convert .py to .exe.
my file is Notepad.py.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get

Comment: What is the error? We can't help otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

If your .py contant any image or database file than you have to tranfer into folder 'dist'.